# How to add a hidden field to form_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-with

I am attempting to add a hidden field to a `form_with`.

Here are 3 attempts (and results / error messages)

#### First attempt

From: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

> <%= hidden_field_tag(:parent_id, "5") %>

So I try:

```
<%= form_with(model: @message, method: :post) do |f| %> 
<%= f.label :body %> 
<%= f.text_area :body %> 
<%= f.hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

#### Second attempt

From: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field

> Example: hidden_field(:signup, :pass_confirm)

So I try

```
<%= f.label :body %> 
<%= f.text_area :body %> 
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

but

[image]

#### Third attempt

This gets further than the other two attempts, because at least the show view loads rather than erroring.

```
<%= form_with(model: @message, method: :post) do |f| %> 
<%= f.label :body %> 
<%= f.text_area :body %> 
<%= f.hidden_field user_id: current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

But the parameter that gets submitted is

```
Unpermitted parameter: :{:user_id=>21}
```

i.e. it contains some extra punctuation that it shouldn't contain (I think it's been made into a nested hash or something?)

Answer (score 8):

You have some error syntax. If you want to pass value to hidden field by using the :value parameter.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked `<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>`

i.e.

```
<%= form_with(model: @message, method: :post) do |f| %> 
<%= f.label :body %> 
<%= f.text_area :body %> 
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Where

- `:user_id` is the name of the parameter (change to your parameter name)
- `value:` is simply telling `form_with` the value is coming next (i.e. don't change that)
- `current_user.id` is the actual value (change to your value)

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12732078/5783745) answer